# Método de busca envolvendo Java e SQL Server

Tags: java, sql

Como fazer uma busca em java passando um atributo do (SQL) como parâmetro?

Resolvi digitar um esboço do cod:

**MAIN**

```
static private void PesquisarUsuario(Connection con) throws SQLException
{
    int cpf;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Pesquisar pes = new Pesquisar();

    System.out.println("Informe o CPF a ser pesquisado:");
    pes.cpf = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    pes.PesquisarUsu(pes, con);



    s.close();
}
```

**CLASS PESQUISAR**

```
public void PesquisarUsu(Pesquisar pes, Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String sql = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    //Não sei apartir daqui de como efetuar a pesquisa

}
```

Comment: Você poderia dar mais informações sobre o que precisa? Tem algo que já fez? [ask]

Comment: Bem! Eu estou montando um sistema de cadastro, alteração e pesquisa envolvendo java e sql. Mas o método de pesquisa me deixou em duvida e não sei como deveria definir ele em java para chamar o sql

Comment: Felipe, por favor use o link de **[edit]** logo abaixo da pergunta para acrescentar mais informações. Tente informar mais detalhes para conseguirmos entender em que ponto exatamente você está com dificuldades, pois da maneira como está a pergunta é ampla demais (mesmo com o seu esclarecimento no comentário anterior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PreparedStatement é uma classe cujo um objeto seu armazena um valor pré compilado de uma sentença SQL. Uma de suas utilidades é fazer pesquisas de modo seguro, pois a sentença SQL é montada setando os parâmetros representados por `?`, evitando assim injeção SQL.

O resultado da query do *prepared statement* é armazenado em um objeto do tipo ResultSet. Percorra esse *result set* com o método `next()` buscando os registros retornado pela query. A cada iteração de `next()`, o objeto de *result set* estará referenciando o próxima registro do resultado.

Exemplo:

```
public void PesquisarUsu(Pesquisar pes, Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE cpf=?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, pes.getCpf());    //coloca a String de pes.getCpf() no 
                                        //lugar do ? na sentença SQL
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(); //executa query e armazena resultado em rs
    while(rs.next()) {   //enquanto tiver resultados, anda para o próxima
        System.out.println("Nome: " + rs.getString("nome")); 
        System.out.println("Idade: " + rs.getInt("idade"));
        System.out.println("Aprovado: " + rs.getBoolean("aprovado"));
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
}
```

No exemplo acima a tabela obrigatoriamente deve possuir os campos `nome` representado em texto, `idade` representado em número e `aprovado` representado em boolean, pois eles devem ser compatíveis com o tipo definido em `rs.getTipo()`.

A quantidade de sentenças `stmt.setTipo()` deve ser exatamente igual a quantidade de parametros (`?`) que possui a sentença sql, ou seja, se houverem mais parametros (`?`) dentro do sql deve-se escrever a mesma quantidade de `stmt.setTipo()` para que seja construída a sentença sql corretamente, substituindo todos os `?` por valores.

Assim como no *result set*, o `tipo` em `stmt.setTipo()` deve ser exatamente o mesmo tipo do segundo parametro do método, ou seja, para `stmt.setString(1, pes.getCpf());` o método `pes.getCpf()` deve retornar uma String. O primeiro parâmetro do método `stmt.setTipo()` é a posição do parâmetro (`?`) dentro da String sql, ou seja, 1, 2, 3...

O `while(rs.next())` é o que comumente usamos para pegar todos os registros dentro do *result set*, entretanto como no seu caso se trata de cpf é possível que somente seja retornado um único registro no query, portanto você também pode tratar o `rs` da seguinte maneira:

```
    if(rs.next()) {   //se houver ao menos um resultados
        System.out.println("Nome: " + rs.getString("nome")); 
        System.out.println("Idade: " + rs.getInt("idade"));
        System.out.println("Aprovado: " + rs.getBoolean("aprovado"));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Nenhum usuario encontrado para cpf: " + pes.getCpf()); 
    }
```

Faça da maneira acima apenas se você tiver certeza que não existirão mais de um registro com o mesmo cpf, caso exista só o primeiro será considerado.

Referências:
[PreparedStatement - Java SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)
[ResultSet - Java SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!
 Obrigado pelo apoio Math!