# Método de Alteração utilizando Java e SQL

Tags: java, sql

Necessito fazer uma alteração em SQL utilizando o Java, mas acabei me perdendo na lógica quando faz a chamada e o retorno para alterar. Segue o esboço do código.

Aqui é o `Main`, onde o usuário informa o CPF que deseja alterar:

```
static private void alterarCliente(Connection con) throws SQLException
{
    String nome, sexo, rua, bairro, cidade, complemento, tipo;
    String cpf, rg, cep, numero, telefone;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cliente cli = new Cliente();

    System.out.println("Informe o CPF do usuario a ser alterado:");
    cli.cpf = s.next();
    cli.AlterarCliente(cli, con);
}
```

Aqui é onde deve puxar os dados do CPF informado e fazer a alteração:

```
public void AlterarCliente(Cliente cli, Connection con) throws SQLException{
    String sql = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
}
```

E por aqui que eu me perdi, pois o método `AlteraCliente()` deve fazer a busca do CPF informado e retornar todos os dados (daquele CPF) para serem alterados.

Comment: `int cpf, rg, cep, telefone;`, cara, não tem a menor condição que uma variável int guarde tais informações, o primeiro passo é tornar essas variáveis do tipo String. Sobre sua dúvida, não ficou claro para mim qual é a dificuldade. Nos diga, o que você deseja que o método `AlterarCliente()` faça?

Comment: Veja se dúvida pode te ajudar: [Método de busca envolvendo Java e SQL Server](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15864/3117), acho que pode ser um caminho. Nos diga se evoluir em algo.

Comment: Bem Math, eu postei aquela pergunta para fazer uma pesquisa e além disso foi bem respondida atingindo minha meta. Se necessário utilizar o Método de pesquisa informado, então como eu deveria fazer o retorno dos dados para que o próprio usuário os altere? Em vez de só mostrar como a Pesquisa faz!

Comment: É verdade! Voce mesmo fez aquela pergunta, rs.. Não tinha percebido. Está um pouco corrido agora pra mim, depois eu dou mais atenção aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vamos resolver uma coisa.

cli.AlterarCliente(cli, con); Isso não faz sentido, estou recebendo como parâmetro eu mesmo.

Outra questão, separe o que é Persistencia do resto do seu sistema, mas se quiser algo mais simples pode fazer da seguinte forma.

```
static private void alterarCliente(Connection con) {
   String nome, sexo, rua, bairro, cidade, complemento, tipo;
   String cpf, rg, cep, numero, telefone;

   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   Cliente cli = new Cliente();

  System.out.println("Informe o CPF do usuario a ser alterado:");
  cli.cpf = s.next();
  //Aqui você precisará preencher todas as propriedades do seu objeto cli.
  //em vez de fazer cli.cpf cli.nome de uma estudada sobre gets e sets.

  if (cli.updateCliente(con)) {
     System.out.println("Alterado com sucesso");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Não foi possível alterar");
  }

}
```

Agora vamos buscar os dados.

```
public void buscaCliente(Connection con) throws SQLException {
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE cpf = ?";
   PreparedStatement stmt = con.preparedStatement(sql);
   stmt.setString(1, cpf);

   ResultSet rs = stmt.execute();

   rs.next();

   nome = rs.getString("nome"); // aqui você coloca a propriedade que vai receber a informação e a coluna na bd como parametro.
   sexo = rs.getString("sexo");
   ... (Segue a mesma logica para todos os campos menos o CPF)
}
```

Agora vamos ao Alterar mesmo.

```
public boolean UpdateCliente(Connection con) throws SQLException{
       String sql = "UPDATE clientes SET nome = ?, sexo = ?, rua = ?, bairro = ?, cidade = ? (Segue a mesma logica para todos os campos menos o CPF) WHERE cpf = ?";
       PreparedStatement stmt = con.preparedStatement(sql);
       stmt.setString(1, nome);
       stmt.setString(2, sexo);
       ... (Segue a mesma logica)
       stmt.setString(X, cpf); //no lugar do x coloca a posição do ? lembrando que começa no 1... Exemplo o nome é a ? numero 1, sexo é ? numero 2 e assim vai.

       return stmt.executeUpdate() > 0; //Aqui já faz o update na tabela e verifica se conseguiu ou não retornando true ou false.
}
```

Algumas observações importantes.
Dessa forma você perde grande parte das funções da OO.
Procure sobre Gets e Sets, alem de separar a parte logica, dos views e da persistencia.