# Utilizar dados que estão no banco de dados

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, jdbc

Estou criando um Quiz. Consegui criar a tela para criar as perguntas, esta gravando no banco de dados tudo certo. Só que agora vou fazer o "jogo" em si, portanto teria que pegar uma pergunta que está guardada no banco e retornar para a tela, como faço essa consulta no banco? `ResultSet` esta dando erro o código abaixo.

```
 String SQL = "Aqui montaria o SQL de Busca de Dificuldades no jogo
 WHERE" ;

 String Nivel=" ";

 if(JrbFácil.isSelected()){ 

 SQL += "DICICULDADE = FACIL"

 }

 if(JrbMédio.isSelected()){

 SQL += "DICICULDADE = MEDIO"

 }

 if(JrbDificil.isSelected()){

 SQL += "DICICULDADE = DIFICIL"

 }

 PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement("select *from quiz where id = ?");

 stmt.setInt(1, 1); 

 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Que erro está dando jovem?

Comment: não esta compilando

Comment: Beleza, poste a saída com o erro de compilação...

Comment: Veja se isso é de alguma ajuda: [Método de busca envolvendo Java e SQL Server](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15864/3117)

Comment: Qual o uso da string `SQL`?

Comment: "Não está compilando" é algo muito genérico. Está exibindo algum erro? Alguma Exception? Só olhando o seu código eu notei pontuações (á, í, ...), vale lembrar que java é case sensitive.

Eu recomendo que refaça a sua pergunta postando o código completo que está usando e se possível informar os campos da tabela que está buscando as informações no banco. Ajude para ser ajudado.

Comment: Você importou o `java.sql.ResultSet`?

Answer (score 1):

1-) Teste a query no banco para ver se está retornando dados.
2-) Verifique se ambos os SELECTS estão corretos, através do passo acima.
3-) Verifique se a aplicação está executando o SELECT.
4-) Não esqueça de colocar um espaço depois do WHERE quando montar a consulta dessa maneira.
5-) Verifique se a conexão está ok.

Usando o result set:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement("select * from quiz where id = ?");

stmt.setInt(1, 1); 

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
String campo1;
String campo2;
while(rs.next()){
 campo1 = rs.getString("NOME DO CAMPO 1");
 campo2 = rs.getString("NOME DO CAMPO 2");
}
```

Lembrando, que é considerado boas práticas usar o nome do campo em vez do indice.

Foram apenas suposições, poste o stacktrace ou o erro de compilação para ajudar na solução do problema

Answer (score 0):

Apesar da pergunta não estar clara, já tentou conferir seu o seu SQL está correto?

```
select *from quiz where id = ?
```

Acho que o correto seria:

```
select * from quiz where id = ?
```

Comment: Qual é a diferença da primeira sintaxe para a segunda?

Comment: Ele esqueceu o * colado no from, possivelmente isso pode dar algum tipo de erro.

Comment: Não altera em nada Renato, acabei de testar.